# XCode 8 ad hoc build from Cordova 6.5.0 won't install on iOS9

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ios9

Problem: I have built an app using Cordova 6.5.0. The app downloads and works perfectly on Android and iOS 10, but it will not install on devices with iOS 9.

I have a download link to a `manifest.plist` file. The link uses an `.ipa` ad hoc XCode build.

Once again, this download fails on devices with iOS 9.

---

When it's downloaded on iOS 9, the downloader receives the error message:

`App kann nicht geladen werden.
[App Name] kann derzeit nicht installiert werden.
Option: Fertig oder Wiederholen`

---

This roughly translates to:

`App can not be loaded.
[App Name] cannot currently be installed.
Option: Finished or Retry`

---

I set the minimum deployment target to 8.0 in Xcode, and I also tried setting the iOS minimum deployment target to 8.0 in Cordova's `config.xml`. None of this has helped.

I tried building and archiving in XCode 7, since the "DTSDKName" is set to "iphoneios10.3", and perhaps this is coming from my XCode 8 build.

The download link still fails with the build from XCode 7.

---

I apologize if this question is vague, but I'd be happy to provide any details that would be helpful.

To make matters more difficult, I only have iOS 9 XCode simulators (I don't have an actual device with iOS 9 to test).

I am not an iOS developer, so I am doing a lot of trial and error. I'm using Cordova, which has made it possible for me to work on this app without Objective-C or Swift knowledge.

That being said. If this is a vague question, I don't mind deleting it. However, I would be grateful if someone might be able to provide me with a little guidance.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that this answers my question: [What is the difference between In House versus Ad Hoc distribution for Enterprise apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858266/what-is-the-difference-between-in-house-versus-ad-hoc-distribution-for-enterpris)

- I needed to assign the release build to an `In House` provisioning profile rather than an `Ad hoc` provisioning profile.
- When I exported the app file, I needed to `Save for Enterprise Deployment` rather than `Save for Ad Hoc Deployment`
- This problem didn't have anything to do with the iOS version, but rather with certain devices not being authorized to download the `Ad-hoc` build. It just so happened that the unauthorized devices were using iOS 9.